# problem with strpos() searching for string with 'ç'

Tags: php, strpos

can someone help me with this problem?

I've used **file_get_contents()** to get all text from a file

the file has the word **Reparaç** on it

**strpos()** is unable to find **Reparaç**

if i look for **Repara** it finds it so the problem is with the **ç**

if i echo the **file_get_contents()** the **ç** appears normally

if i write the **file_get_contents()** information to another file a strange symbol appears instead of the **ç**

i'm really tired of doing stuff and searching around to try to fix this and it's probably something easy that people that are used to do php code are pretty used to dealing with but i can't figure out what's wrong with this

by the way, in many websites that i saw it seemed that the charset could be relevant for problems of this kind, i'm using **UTF-8**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php)

Comment: **mb_strpos()** didn't worked, **file_get_contents()** may be messing up the **ç** when it returns the file text as a string

Comment: @wxiiir Verify that file in UTF-8 charset, and if not convert it to UTF-8 with iconv()

Comment: @php-coder thank you for telling me to verify that the file was on utf-8 charset, for some weird reason the file from where **file_get_contents()** was getting the info. that was supposed to be **utf-8** was in fact **windows-1252** that's why it could never work. i always select my files to be utf-8 so i probably didn't noticed i chose it wrong this time. **strpos** and **mb_strpos** both work well now. thank you

Comment: @tttony didn't tried that method because i've solved the problem first and without using any extra code, somehow i messed up when choosing file charset. thank you for your answer

Comment: @wxiiir I know that you had a problem there so I recommend you to `utf8_decode()` the content, but it's better to change the file enconding to UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/mb_strpos) instead, which is multibyte aware - strpos is for oldschool ASCII and will barf on Unicode strings.

Comment: **mb_strpos()** didn't worked, it is multibyte aware as you said but **file_get_contents()** may be messing up the **ç** when it returns the file text as a string and so i'm stuck with the problem again